# AI engine for iOS game development?

Tags: ai, ios, objective-c

I'm looking for an AI engine for iOS game development (machine learning, path finding).

Comment: You're more likely to find middleware for specific purposes rather than a general AI package. EG a pathfinding package, steering, behaviour tree implementation, etc. Could you be more specific about what needs you have?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, just remember that anything written in standard C or C++ should work on iOS, it does not have to be Objective-C

Answer (score 4):

As @slf commented any C/C++ code can be compiled for iOS devices. so you can use any of these libraries:

1. [dlib](http://dlib.net/) is a library which has many useful tools including machine learning.
2. [MicroPather](http://www.grinninglizard.com/MicroPather/) is a path finder and A* solver (astar or a-star) written in platform independent C++ that can be easily integrated into existing code.
3. [Here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/List+Of+Libraries#Artificial_intelligence) is a list of some AI libraries suggested on OGRE3D website. Seems they are mostly written in C++ and at least most of them are not depended on OGRE engine itself.